# Parsing json in python 3.7 within a joblib.Parallel

Tags: json, python-3.7, joblib

I'm doing that in python3.7

```
Parallel(n_jobs=nthread)(delayed(parseKronosJson)(parameters)for j in range(len(filesInFolderList)))
```

In `parseKronosJson` I parse a Json (each call corresponding of one different json) and if `nthread` is above 1 I've got random errors like that :

```
  File "/Users/.../ArchiveAnalysis.py", line 385, in loadArchiveJSON
    self.archiveDic[keyList[file]] = jm.loadJSON(filePath)
  File "/Users/../JSON_Methods.py", line 31, in loadJSON
    return json.load(jsonFile)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 296, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 19528 column 2 (char 583412)
```

So my question is json parsing incompatible with Joblib?

Comment: Why do you have a second `Parallel` call nested inside the first one? Can you improve your code formatting and post a runnable [MCVE] with sample data?

Comment: It was a Typo
`Parallel(n_jobs=nthread)(delayed(parseKronosJson)(parameters)for j in range(len(filesInFolderList)))`